# Is the spherical coordinate system a vector space?

Tags: differential-geometry, vector-spaces, spherical-coordinates

There are basis in spherical coordinate system but I think it does not satisfy vector axioms.
Is calling them basis an abuse of notation?
Edit:Look in the comments of accepted answer for the complete answer.

Comment: There is a problem with the origin, for which we can only say radius is $0$ and angle down from north is $90$ degrees, but the third coordinate, for longitude, can be anything. In this sense the spherical coordinate system is not unique for the origin.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @coffeemath is this the only problem? Because I think that in spherical coordinate we add the angles and r vector. So we can set zero vector r=0 and both angles=0. That way we would get a unique zero vector.
For any other zero vector where both angles are not zero we could add zero vector to another vector and change their angle .

Comment: What exacly is it that you (or someone) is calling “basis”? Are you talking about $(\mathbf{e}_r,\mathbf{e}_\theta,\mathbf{e}_\phi)$?

Comment: @Hans Lundmark Yes , I am talking about them.

Comment: coordinate systems are ways to identify a point in some space. there are no implicit operations on these hypothetical coordinates

Comment: @steamsteam "*points in the coordinate space*" $\;-\;$ There is no "*coordinate space*". Coordinates are one way of identifying points that lie in a space, and there are different coordinate systems that will describe the same points differently. The properties of the space the points lie in does not depend on the coordinate system used to describe them. Your question is akin to "*does the distributive property in arithmetic hold for numbers written in roman numerals*".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For any point $P$ not on the $z$-axis, the vector triple
$$
\bigl( \mathbf{e}_r(P),\mathbf{e}_\theta(P),\mathbf{e}_\phi(P) \bigr)
$$
indeed is an ON-basis for $\mathbf{R}^3$. (Or maybe rather for the tangent space to $\mathbf{R}^3$ at the point $P$, if that distinction makes any sense to you.)

But that doesn't mean that the spherical coordinate system is a vector space. What would it even *mean* for a *coordinate system* to be a *vector space*?

Comment: it would mean it satisfies the axioms of a vector space?

Comment: What would it even mean for a coordinate system to be a vector space?
I meant that if we take a tuple of three real numbers first real number is r second and third are the angles. We say that the tuple is a vector
Then define addition such that sum of tuple is sum of each of it's component. Multiplying tuple with a scalar would multiply each element of tuple with the scalar. Then we say that tuple is a element of vector space. So it follows the vector axioms.

Then would that vector space correspond with coordinate space. So adding two vectors in our vector space would be same as adding

Comment: two points in the coordinate space.
For example when we add two vectors we get 1 2 2 but when add two points of spherical coordinate space we get 1 3 2 or something.
I am not sure about how a coordinate system is defined mathematically which is why i asked this question

Comment: @steamsteam: A vector space is a set of elements (“vectors”) together with operations satisfying certain axioms. A coordinate system is a mapping into $\mathbf{R}^n$ from (a subset of) the space you want to coordinatize, with certain properties. So vector spaces and coordinates systems are completely different mathematical objects, and it makes no sense to say that they are equal.

Comment: The property you're describing is **linearity** of the coordinate mapping, which makes sense to ask about provided that the space you're coordinatizing is a vector space to begin with. And for spherical coordinates, this mapping is not linear.

Comment: @DavidP: And what would *that* mean, exactly? What are the vectors and the operations of a coordinate system? (Cf. my two comments above.)